# How do I conveniently plot any implicit function in desmos without repetitions of code and typing?

Tags: desmos

Desmos does plot circle when I enter:

```
x2+y2=1
```

But when I enter:

```
f(x,y)=1

f(x,y)=x2+y2
```

It doesn't plot anything.

This problem does not exist with explicit functions, e.g. when I enter:

```
f(x)+g(x)

f(x)=x2

g(x)=x3
```

That is the same as:

```
x2+x3
```

Desmos does plot some cubic function.

So I can conveniently plot any explicit function without repetitions of code and typing, but not implicit functions.

Why? Does exist workaround to achieve the same goal/aim/purpose also with implicit functions too?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that because you're defining `f(x,y)` twice.

First let's understand the difference between 2 kinds of Desmos statements: **Equations** and **Function Definitions**.

These are all **equations**:

```
y = 1
y = x
y = x ^ 2 - x + 14
x ^ 2 + y ^ 2 = 1
x + y = 1
x / y = y / x
sin(x) = e^y
```

They're all relationships between `x` and `y`. Desmos can and will always plot equations as long as they only use `x` and `y` as variables.

These are **function definitions**:

```
f(x) = x
g(x) = x ^ 2 - 2 * x + 1
D(j) = j ^ j
C(y) = e ^ y
h(x, y) = x + y - x * y
```

They're like equations, but instead of typing `y` we give the equation a name, e.g. `f(x)` and then define it. The first 4 functions take one parameter, so they can be transformed to an equation and **will be plotted**:

```
f(x) = x                             //y = x
g(x) = x ^ 2 - 2 * x + 1             //y = x ^ 2 - 2 * x + 1
D(j) = j ^ j                         //y = x ^ x
C(y) = e ^ y                         //y = e ^ x
```

However the last one takes *two* parameters, so it **can't** be plotted on the plane.

Now back to the question, try doing this:

```
f(x, y) = 1
f(x, y) = x ^ 2 + y ^ 2
f(0, 0)
```

The last line will throw an error:

> You've defined 'f' in more than one place. Try picking a different variable, or deleting some of the definitions of 'f'.

And that's exactly the issue, you defined the function `f(x, y)` in two spots, so Desmos can't tell which one to use to resolve your inquiry.

In the second example, you define `f(x)` once and `g(x)` once, and then you tell Desmos to plot the equation `f(x) + g(x)` which is basically `y = f(x) + g(x) = x ^ 2 + x ^ 3`.

Another thing is, your `f(x, y)` function takes two parameters so it'll **never** be plotted even if it was correctly defined once, because it's 3 dimensional but Desmos is in 2D.

For example:

```
f(x, y) = 3 x ^ 2 + x * y - 1
```

This function will be defined successfully without throwing, but won't be plotted because it's 3 dimensional. You can only plot one 2 dimensional 'slice' of it at a time:

```
g(x) = f(x,0)
```

This will plot.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of the situation back in 2018 when the question was posed and an answer was given.

But today in 2021, on https://www.desmos.com/calculator ...

You can get a circle implicitly with these two statements

```
f(x,y)=x^2+y^2
1=f(x,y)
```

A set of circles

```
f(x,y)=x^2+y^2
[1...5]^2=f(x,y)
```

A set of ellipses

```
f(x,y)=x^2+y^2
[1...5]^2=f([1...5]x,y)
```

A set of boxier circles

```
f(x,y)=x^2+y^2
[1...5]^2=f(x^2,y^2)

g(x,y)=x^4+y^4
[1,3,...,5]^2=g(x,y)
```